# Exit lambda expression through another method

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

i have a program that starts a datatype conversion by clicking a button. I am using a lambda function for my button command. Before the conversion starts a method checks wether an input has been selected or not. Now if there hasn´t been selected an input file i get an error message in jupyter notebook, which isn´t necessarily a problem since the datatype conversion shouldn´t start anyways. Yet i ask myself if there is a way to stop the continuation of the lambda function. I will add a snippet of my code and further explain what i mean:

My button command:

```
self.program_start["command"]=lambda:[self.fileselectwarning(),self.writealldatafile(),self.writeselecteddata(),
                                         self.inputliste.clear(),self.fileopeningcounter.set(0),
                                         self.inputfilenamelist.clear()]
```

The method that checks if an input/outputfile has been selected:

```
def fileselectwarning(self):
    stringliste=[self.fileopenname.get(),self.filesavename.get()]
    if stringliste[0]=="" and not stringliste[1]=="":
        self.messagebox1 = messagebox.showwarning("Missing Inputfile","No Inputfile selected, please select one and retry!")
    elif not stringliste[0]=="" and stringliste[1]=="":
        self.messagebox2 = messagebox.showwarning("Missing Outputfile","No Outputfilename selected, please select one and retry!")
    elif stringliste[0]=="" and stringliste[1]=="":
        self.messagebox3 = messagebox.showwarning("Missing Files","Neither Input nor Outputfile were selected, please select both and retry!")
    elif not stringliste[0]=="" and not stringliste[1]=="":
        ausfuehrenderdatenverarbeitung=self.zugriffaufdatenverarb()
```

So, in my method fileselectwarning, when both an input- and outputfile have been selected another method gets called which starts part of the conversion. and then  all the other methods in the lambda function of my button get called which depend on lists being created in the method that got called through my "fileselectwarning" method. BUT if an input or outputfile are missing the lambdafunction continues and these lists haven´t been created, therefor creating the error.

To round this up, is there a way to stop the lambda function from continuing 
and implementing it in the "fileselectwarning" method?

Comment: Instead of abusing a list constructor to call the functions as side effect, write a regular function.

Comment: can you elaborate, where do you mean should i write the regular function? Instead of the lambda expression ?

Comment: Yes. I try to write an answer that demonstrates what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of abusing a list constructor in a lambda expression to call the functions as side effect, write a regular function.

In order to abort the execution, you could use a custom exception, which is raised by `fileselectwarning`. That function itself could be simplified as well.

```
class MissingFiles(Exception):
    pass

class ...:
    def fileselectwarning(self):
        infile, outfile = self.fileopenname.get(), self.filesavename.get()
        if not infile and outfile:
            raise MissingFiles("No Inputfile selected, please select one and retry!")
        elif infile and not outfile:
            raise MissingFiles("No Outputfilename selected, please select one and retry!")
        elif not infile and not outfile:
            raise MissingFiles("Neither Input nor Outputfile were selected, please select both and retry!")
        else:
            ausfuehrenderdatenverarbeitung=self.zugriffaufdatenverarb()

    def start_command(self):
        try:
            self.fileselectwarning()
        except MissingFiles as e:
            self.messagebox1 = messagebox.showwarning("Missing files", str(e))
            return
        self.writealldatafile()
        self.writeselecteddata()
        self.inputliste.clear()
        self.fileopeningcounter.set(0)
        self.inputfilenamelist.clear()
```

Then when assigning the command, do:

```
    self.program_start["command"] = self.start_command
```

Obviously I couldn't test this, so it might not work right away, but it shows the general idea.

Comment: You can either use regular, instance methods and pass in self as the argument, or staticmethods without self. I mean, it will be perfectly valid syntactically, it just won't behave how you'd expect.

Comment: @user8407600: Given `start_command` uses `self` internally, you definitely don't want to make it a `@staticmethod`, since the function isn't passed an instance when called, but requires an instance to call the methods upon. Assigning `self.start_command` to `self.program_start["command"]` makes it a bound method, so it can be called with no arguments, but still passes `self` correctly (because the bound method hides it internally).